# xsl: transforming a list into a 2-D table

Tags: xml, xslt

Let's say I have this XML node:

```
<items>
    <item>...<item>
    <item>...<item>
    <item>...<item>
    <item>...<item>
    <item>...<item>
    ...
</items>
```

where there are N `item` nodes.

Now I would like to transform it into an HTML table with 4 columns. (e.g. if N=12, there are 3 complete rows, and if N=27, there are 7 rows, the last having 3 cells)

How could I go about doing this?

My gut call is to do it this way, where `{{something}}` is what I don't know how to implement:

```
<xsl:template match="items">
   <table>
      <xsl:call-template name="partition-items">
         <xsl:with-param name="skip" select="0" />
      </xsl:call-template>
   </table>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="partition-items">
    <xsl:param name="skip" />
    {{ if # of items in current node > $skip,
          output a row, 
          and call partition-items($skip+4)
    }}
<xsl:template />
```

The pieces I don't know how to implement, are

- how to make a predicate for testing the # of `item` elements in the current node
- how to get the Nth `item` element in the current node

**Update from comments**

> How to pad the last row with empty
>   `<td />` elements so that each row
>   contains exactly the wanted cells?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the probably shortest solution that doesn't even use any explicit recursion. :)

Comment: Added an XSLT 2.0 solution, too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's my **working solution**.

As you didn't provide a desired output, this particular one may be uncomplete for your needs.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table>
            <xsl:call-template name="make-columns">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodelist" select="item"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="make-columns">
        <xsl:param name="nodelist"/>
        <xsl:param name="columns-number" select="4"/>

        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$nodelist[
                            not(position() > $columns-number)
                            ]"/>
        </tr>

        <!-- If some nodes are left, recursively call current
        template, passing only nodes that are left -->
        <xsl:if test="count($nodelist) > $columns-number">
            <xsl:call-template name="make-columns">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodelist" select="$nodelist[
                                        position() > $columns-number
                                        ]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test input:**

```
<items>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>13</item>
    <item>14</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>16</item>
    <item>17</item>
    <item>18</item>
    <item>19</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>21</item>
    <item>22</item>
    <item>23</item>
    <item>24</item>
    <item>25</item>
    <item>26</item>
    <item>27</item>
</items>
```

**Output:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>27</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Do note:** you can pass columns number dynamically.

**Additional requirements and edit.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="http://localhost"
    exclude-result-prefixes="my">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <my:layout>
        <td/><td/><td/><td/>
        <td/><td/><td/><td/>
        <td/><td/><td/><td/>
        <td/><td/><td/><td/>
    </my:layout>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table>
            <xsl:call-template name="make-columns">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodelist" select="item"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="make-columns">
        <xsl:param name="nodelist"/>
        <xsl:param name="columns-number" select="4"/>

        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$nodelist[
                            not(position() > $columns-number)
                            ]"/>
            <xsl:if test="count($nodelist) &lt; $columns-number">
                <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/my:layout/td[
                    position() &lt;= $columns-number - count($nodelist)
                    ]"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </tr>

        <!-- If some nodes are left, recursively call current
        template, passing only nodes that are left -->
        <xsl:if test="count($nodelist) > $columns-number">
            <xsl:call-template name="make-columns">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodelist" select="$nodelist[
                                        position() > $columns-number
                                        ]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It can be applied to the previous sample or to this concise XML:

```
<items>
    <item>1</item>
</items>
```

Result will be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://localhost"></td>
        <td xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://localhost"></td>
        <td xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://localhost"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Do note:**

1. Hardcoded data to add elements, when there are less `item` elements than number of columns is.
2. Extra hardcoded elements, if number of columns will ever change.

If there won't ever be less  elements than number of columns, you can just apply to the `item` elements with the same predicate and a different `mode`.

**And last edit.** With a counted loop.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table>
            <xsl:call-template name="make-columns">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodelist" select="item"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="make-columns">
        <xsl:param name="nodelist"/>
        <xsl:param name="columns-number" select="4"/>

        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$nodelist[
                            not(position() > $columns-number)
                            ]"/>
            <xsl:if test="count($nodelist) &lt; $columns-number">
                <xsl:call-template name="empty-cells">
                    <xsl:with-param name="finish" select="$columns-number - count($nodelist)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </tr>

        <!-- If some nodes are left, recursively call current
        template, passing only nodes that are left -->
        <xsl:if test="count($nodelist) > $columns-number">
            <xsl:call-template name="make-columns">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodelist" select="$nodelist[
                                        position() > $columns-number
                                        ]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="empty-cells">
        <xsl:param name="finish"/>
        <td/>
        <xsl:if test="not($finish = 1)">
            <xsl:call-template name="empty-cells">
                <xsl:with-param name="finish" select="$finish - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How could you edit it so that it padded the last row with empty <td /> elements so that each row contains 4 cells?

Comment: the `copy-of` in the edited update seems to cause an error in Firefox.... I think I'm just going to add a `call-template` and pass in `count($nodelist) - $columns-number`

Comment: @Jason S, Works well im my 3.6. May be namespace uri resolving issue. Yes, you can just use a small finite loop. I will post an update. I guess this would be a better way.

Comment: @Flack: +1 For big effort, beside I think last correct solution has to many named templates...

Comment: @Alejandro. Not so many ways for incapsulation in XSLT. Though I agree, I still think it's pretty much a question of style.

Comment: @Flack: Adding an answer, too.

Answer (score 5):

I. XSLT 1.0 solution:

**Here is probably one of the shortest possible solutions that notably doesn't require explicit recursion**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="pNumCols" select="4"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <table>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() mod $pNumCols =1]"/>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select=
    ". | following-sibling::*[not(position() >= $pNumCols)]"/>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item" mode="copy">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<items>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>13</item>
    <item>14</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>16</item>
    <item>17</item>
    <item>18</item>
    <item>19</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>21</item>
    <item>22</item>
    <item>23</item>
    <item>24</item>
    <item>25</item>
    <item>26</item>
    <item>27</item>
</items>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>24</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>27</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The wanted number of cells per row is specified in the external/global parameter** `$pNumCols`.
2. **Templates are applied only on such children of the top element, whose position is the start of a new row** -- they are generated by the expression `$k * $pNumCols +1`, where $k can be any integer.
3. **The template that processing each row-starting item creates a row (`tr` element) and within it applies templates in a special mode `"copy"`** for the `$pNumCols` starting with itself.
4. **The template matching an `item` in mode `"copy"` simply creates a cell (`td` element)** and outputs inside it the string value of the `item` element being matched.

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="pNumCols" select="4"/>

    <xsl:template match="items">
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="item"
            group-by="(position()-1) idiv $pNumCols">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**applied on the same XML document as before, this transformation produces the same, correct result.**

**Explanation**:

1. **The [`<xsl:for-each-group>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#xsl-for-each-group) instruction is used** to select the different groups of `item` elements where each group contains the elements that must be represented in one row.
2. **The standard XPath 2.0 operator [`idiv`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#prod-xpath-MultiplicativeExpr) is used** for this purpose.
3. **The XSLT 2.0 function [`current-group()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#current-group) contains all items that must be presented in the current row**.

Answer (score 1):

Just for style, this XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="pColumns" select="4"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() mod $pColumns = 1]"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:variable name="vItems"
                      select=".|following-sibling::*[$pColumns > position()]"/>
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$vItems" mode="makeCell"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="fillRow">
                <xsl:with-param name="pItems" 
                                select="$pColumns - count($vItems)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item" mode="makeCell">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="fillRow">
        <xsl:param name="pItems" select="0"/>
        <xsl:if test="$pItems">
            <td/>
            <xsl:call-template name="fillRow">
                <xsl:with-param name="pItems" select="$pItems - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With @Flack's answer input, output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td />
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With for-each-group you can get a more elegant solution:

```
<xsl:template match="items">
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="ceiling(position() div $column_width)">
      <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: this creates a table with four rows, not a table with 4 columns!

Comment: Thank you. Replaced a mod b by ceiling(a div b)

Comment: There is an `idiv` operator (integer division) in XPath/XSLT 2.0