# XSL: Transforming xml into a sorted multicolumn html table

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking at a similar problem to what was covered here

[Transforming List into a 2-D Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846065/xsl-transforming-a-list-into-a-2-d-table)

but with a slight wrinkle. My XML is not in any particular order and I would like to sort it for display.  For example my XML is

```
<items>  
  <item>A</item>  
  <item>C</item>  
  <item>E</item>  
  <item>B</item>  
  <item>D</item> 
  <!-- ... any number of item nodes ... -->
<item>
```

and I want my output to be (where I am ignoring the non-named nodes for illustrative purposes)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td />
    </tr>
</table>
```

The XSL I am basing this off is from the above link (I need to use XSL 1.0):

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <table>
        <xsl:call-template name="make-columns">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodelist" select="item"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="make-columns">
    <xsl:param name="nodelist"/>
    <xsl:param name="columns-number" select="3"/>

    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$nodelist[
                        not(position() > $columns-number)
                        ]"/>
        <xsl:if test="count($nodelist) &lt; $columns-number">
            <xsl:call-template name="empty-cells">
                <xsl:with-param name="finish" 
                                select="$columns-number - count($nodelist)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </tr>

    <!-- If some nodes are left, recursively call current
    template, passing only nodes that are left -->
    <xsl:if test="count($nodelist) > $columns-number">
        <xsl:call-template name="make-columns">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodelist" select="$nodelist[
                                    position() > $columns-number
                                    ]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="empty-cells">
    <xsl:param name="finish"/>
    <td/>
    <xsl:if test="not($finish = 1)">
        <xsl:call-template name="empty-cells">
            <xsl:with-param name="finish" select="$finish - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried inserting  commands within the various apply-templates but that doesn't work.

ideas?

Jeff

**Update from comments**

> I want to output a multicolum table
>   with 3 columns where the entries are
>   in alphabetical order vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNumCols" select="3"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNumRows" select=
      "ceiling(count(/*/*) div $pNumCols)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfSorted">
   <xsl:for-each select="/*/*">
    <xsl:sort/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vSorted"
      select="ext:node-set($vrtfSorted)/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <table>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "$vSorted[not(position() > $vNumRows)]"/>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <tr>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "(.|following-sibling::*[position() mod $vNumRows =0])/text()"/>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<items>
    <item>A</item>
    <item>C</item>
    <item>E</item>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>D</item>
</items>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Jeffrey-Hersh: At SO you are expected to accept one of the two answers -- both @Alejandro and I have provided correct and good answerd. To accept an answer click on the green check-mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Now, with new requeriment explained, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="pColumns" select="3"/>
    <xsl:template match="items">
        <xsl:variable name="vrtfChilds">
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:sort/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="vChilds" select="msxsl:node-set($vrtfChilds)/*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vRows" 
                      select="ceiling(count($vChilds) div $pColumns)"/>
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vChilds[$vRows >= position()]">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:call-template name="columns">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pRows" select="$vRows"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="columns">
        <xsl:param name="pData" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="pColumn" select="$pColumns"/>
        <xsl:param name="pRows" select="0"/>
        <xsl:if test="$pColumn">
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$pData"/>
            </td>
            <xsl:call-template name="columns">
                <xsl:with-param name="pData"
                     select="$pData/following-sibling::*[$pRows]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pColumn" select="$pColumn - 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pRows" select="$pRows"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Note**: `node-set` extension function for a two phase transformation.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't quite work.  While, it works fine for the order of the XML I specified as an example. However, let's say, for example, I add an item <item>F</item> anywhere within the XML. The XSL will not sort it in the order I need it (first row: A C E, second row: B D F).

Comment: @Jeffrey Hersh: You wrote _"that doesn't quite work"_ and also _"it works fine"_. I think you need to make up your mind... If there is some sorting involve, you should describe that in your questions.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear.  Your solution works fine for the illustrative example I put up, but it does not work in the general case. The general case it what I need.

Comment: Sorry...  To be specific I have a long xml file with various nodes with various children fields.  I want to sort on one of those children field to have a multicolumn table in alphabetical order on that specified.  So in the illustrative case I posted my xml can have any number of <item> entries and those entries can be in any order.  I want to output a multicolum table with 3 columns where the entries are in alphabetical order vertically. That is the general case I am talking about.