# alternate sorted nodes in XSLT 1.0 without extension function

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This a very similar question as [XSL: Transforming xml into a sorted multicolumn html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543735/xsl-transforming-xml-into-a-sorted-multicolumn-html-table)

But (unfortunately) there's an extra requirement: it should be XSLT 1.0 without extension functions, i.e. without using the node-set function.

This is my simplified XML:

```
<demo>
  <config n_columns="3" />
  <messages>
    <msg date="2011-07-06" title="2nd message" />
    <title>message list</title>
    <msg date="2011-07-05" title="4th message" />
    <msg date="2011-07-06" title="3rd message" />
    <msg date="2011-07-07" title="1st message" />
  </messages>
</demo>
```

Using this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="demo/messages">
      <xsl:with-param name="n_columns" select="number(/demo/config/@n_columns)" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="messages">
    <xsl:param name="n_columns" />
    <div>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(./title, ' (', $n_columns, ' columns)')" />
    </div>
    <table>
      <xsl:variable name="cells" select="msg" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$cells[(position() - 1) mod $n_columns = 0]"
        mode="row">
        <xsl:with-param name="n_columns" select="$n_columns" />
        <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="$cells" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="msg" mode="row">
    <xsl:param name="n_columns" />
    <xsl:param name="cells" />
    <xsl:variable name="n_row" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="row_cells"
      select="$cells[position() > ($n_row - 1) * $n_columns][position() &lt;= $n_columns]" />
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$row_cells" mode="cell" />
      <xsl:call-template name="empty-cells">
        <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n_columns - count($row_cells)" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="msg" mode="cell">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="empty-cells">
    <xsl:param name="n" />
    <xsl:if test="$n > 0">
      <td>
        <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
          <xsl:value-of select="$n" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
      </td>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces this HTML fragment as output:

```
<div>message list (3 columns)</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2nd message</td>
    <td>4th message</td>
    <td>3rd message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1st message</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What is obviously missing is the sort part...

Redefining the "cells" variable as follows is actually what I need:

```
<xsl:variable name="cells">
  <xsl:for-each select="msg">
    <xsl:sort select="@date" order="descending" />
    <xsl:sort select="@title" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

But now I must define another variable to convert the RTF to a nodelist and pass that one to the template I'm applying.

```
<xsl:variable name="sCells" select="ext:node-set($cells)/*" />
```

Doing that would produce the following HTML fragment:

```
<div>message list (3 columns)</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1st message</td>
    <td>2nd message</td>
    <td>3rd message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4th message</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, my XSLT engine (SAP XML toolkit for java) doesn't support this (or a similar) extension function. Thus I'm looking for another solution that doesn't require the node-set extension function.

I spent quite some time reading all kinds of forums etc., but I really can't figure it out. Perhaps someone has a good idea for an alternative approach? tnx!

---

This is the follow up based on Dimitre's (slightly extended) solution.
This XML input

```
<demo>
  <config n_columns="3" />
  <messages>
    <msg date="2011-07-06" title="2nd message" />
    <title>message list</title>
    <msg date="2011-07-05" title="4th message" />
    <msg date="2011-07-06" title="3rd message" />
    <msg date="2011-07-07" title="1st message" />
    <msg date="2011-07-05" title="5th message" />
    <msg date="2011-07-05" title="7th message" />
    <msg date="2011-07-05" title="6th message" />
  </messages>
</demo>
```

combined with this XSLT stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:variable name="vNumCols" select="/*/config/@n_columns" />
  <xsl:variable name="vCells" select="/*/messages/msg" />
  <xsl:variable name="vNumCells" select="count($vCells)" />
  <xsl:variable name="vNumRows" select="ceiling($vNumCells div $vNumCols)" />
  <xsl:variable name="vIndexPatternLength"
    select="string-length(concat('', $vNumCells))" />
  <xsl:variable name="vIndexPattern">
    <xsl:call-template name="padding">
      <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$vIndexPatternLength" />
      <xsl:with-param name="chars" select="'0'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="vSortedIndex">
    <xsl:for-each select="$vCells">
      <xsl:sort select="@date" order="descending" />
      <xsl:sort select="@title" />
      <xsl:value-of
        select="format-number(count(preceding-sibling::msg) + 1,
          $vIndexPattern)" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="demo/messages" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="messages">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="$vCells[not(position() > $vNumRows)]">
        <xsl:variable name="vRow" select="position()" />
        <tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="$vCells[not(position() > $vNumCols)]">
            <xsl:variable name="vCol" select="position()" />
            <xsl:variable name="vCell"
              select="($vRow - 1) * $vNumCols + $vCol" />
            <xsl:variable name="vIndex"
              select="substring($vSortedIndex,
                ($vCell - 1) * $vIndexPatternLength + 1,
                $vIndexPatternLength)" />
            <xsl:variable name="vMessage"
              select="$vCells[position() = $vIndex]" />
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$vMessage">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$vMessage"
                  mode="cell" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="empty-cell" />
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="msg" mode="cell">
    <td>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="msg">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@date, ' : ', @title)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="empty-cell">
    <td>
      <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/padding/ -->
  <xsl:template name="padding">
    <xsl:param name="length" select="0" />
    <xsl:param name="chars" select="' '" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($length) or not($chars)" />
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="string"
          select="concat($chars, $chars, $chars, $chars, $chars, 
                         $chars, $chars, $chars, $chars, $chars)" />
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="string-length($string) >= $length">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 1, $length)" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="padding">
              <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length" />
              <xsl:with-param name="chars" select="$string" />
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces this HTML output

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2011-07-07 : 1st message</td>
    <td>2011-07-06 : 2nd message</td>
    <td>2011-07-06 : 3rd message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2011-07-05 : 4th message</td>
    <td>2011-07-05 : 5th message</td>
    <td>2011-07-05 : 6th message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2011-07-05 : 7th message</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks Dimitre!

Comment: Does your XSLT processor support inine Javascript extension functions?

Comment: Unfortunately not. However it does support custom java extension functions. So as a last resort, I could try to implement my own node-set function. But that doesn't seem that obvious and the code would be tied to the (closed source) implementation of the XSLT processor.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete XSLT 1.0 solution that doesn't use any extension functions. :)

Comment: I think the simple answer is not to use that XSLT processor; as far a I remember, it has been out of maintenance for many many years.

Comment: @Julian You're probably right, it is indeed pretty outdated. But I didn't have much choice. I use this stylesheet in the context of WPC (Web Page Composer) and the internal WPC framework selects the XSLT processor without a possibility for me to influence this (besides changing the framework itself). Actually it simply uses "TransformerFactory.newInstance();" which gets the default XSLT processor and that (still) happens to be an instance of "com.sap.engine.lib.jaxp.TransformerFactoryImpl". I suppose I could change the default on the entire system, but... At least this is the case on NW7.0.

Comment: @Ziggy: I happened to work on Netweaver a long time ago and recall clearly that we moved to JDK-XSLT. This may be a misconfig of your system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is difficult, but not impossible to perform the required processing in XSLT 1.0 without using any extension functions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNumCols"
      select="/*/config/@n_columns"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vItems" select="/*/messages/msg"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNumItems" select="count($vItems)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNumRows" select=
   "ceiling($vNumItems div $vNumCols)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vsortedInds">
  <xsl:for-each select="$vItems">
   <xsl:sort select="@date" order="descending"/>

   <xsl:value-of select=
   "format-number(count(preceding-sibling::msg)+1,
                  '0000'
                  )
   "/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <table>
   <xsl:for-each select=
   "$vItems[not(position() > $vNumRows)]">
     <tr>
       <xsl:variable name="vRow" select="position()"/>

       <xsl:for-each select="$vItems[not(position() > $vNumCols)]">
          <xsl:variable name="vcurIndIndex" select=
           "($vRow -1)*$vNumCols + position()"/>
          <xsl:variable name="vcurInd" select=
          "substring($vsortedInds, 4*($vcurIndIndex -1) +1, 4)"/>

          <xsl:variable name="vcurItem" select="$vItems[position()=$vcurInd]"/>
          <xsl:if test="$vcurItem">
           <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vcurItem/@title"/>
           </td>
          </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<demo>
    <config n_columns="3" />
    <messages>
        <msg date="2011-07-06" title="2nd message" />
        <title>message list</title>
        <msg date="2011-07-05" title="4th message" />
        <msg date="2011-07-06" title="3rd message" />
        <msg date="2011-07-07" title="1st message" />
    </messages>
</demo>
```

**the significant part of the desired output is produced** (I am leaving the rest as an exercise to the reader :) ):

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1st message</td>
      <td>2nd message</td>
      <td>3rd message</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>4th message</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **In order to avoid having to convert an RTF to a node-set, we are using a string of the indexes of the sorted elements**. Every index occupies four characters (left padded with zeroes when necessary). Then we are using these indexes in populating the rows of the table.
2. **In order to avoid resursion**, we are using the [**Piez method**](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9940e300) of iteration through N non-node items.

**Do note**: This solution assumes that the table will not contain more than 9999 cells. If more cells are expected, you can easily change the code, for example:

Replace:

```
format-number(count(preceding-sibling::msg)+1,
                      '0000'
                    )
```

with:

```
format-number(count(preceding-sibling::msg)+1,
                      '00000'
                    )
```

And replace:

```
          <xsl:variable name="vcurInd" select=
          "substring($vsortedInds, 4*($vcurIndIndex -1) +1, 4)"/>
```

with

```
          <xsl:variable name="vcurInd" select=
          "substring($vsortedInds, 5*($vcurIndIndex -1) +1, 5)"/>
```

Comment: Wow, this is really amazing! It's working and at first sight I understand the logic behind it. Right now I'm investigating this answer a bit further before closing the question.

Comment: @Ziggy: Glad you find this answer useful. Here at SO the official way of expressing gratitude is by accepting the best answer (by clicking on the green check-mark sign next to the answer).

Comment: Yep, now I really understand what is going on and why this is actually working. First sort the node and concatenate the sorted indexes as a string. In this example vSortedInds='0004000100030002'. Then loop through vNumRows x vNumColumns, calculate the current cell position, get the index from the calculated "index substring" (e.g. cell 2 => '0001') and then get the actual node from vItems based on the position. Sweet! I'll extend it a bit to make it more flexible, but the underlying algorithm is perfect. Thank you VERY much!